# Python if else statement is not functioning

Tags: python

My if else statement is not functioning within the code below, I am executing this bit of python using my terminal and as soon as I input 4 or 5,  the program terminates and goes back to the prompt. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import webbrowser

print '\033[0;37;40m' + "Title: The interlinked bit (the index)"
print "Heading: Links!"
print "Paragraph Some Interesting stuff can be found here"
print "Paragraph: And some other bits are also available"
print "1: ./page4.html"
print "2: /page5.html"

pageNumber = raw_input("Enter 4 or 5: ")
if pageNumber == 4:
  print "A Page of stuff"; 
  print "Actually this is all rather dull, why don't you look here           instead, or alternatively    go back  to the index";
elif pageNumber == 5:
  print "Another page of stuff"
  print "Nothing very much here, you should probably try here instead, or       perhaps go back to the index"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because the returned type from `raw_input` is a `str` not an `int`

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant language tags to your question, this is not `java`

Comment: Why has this question been devoted?

Comment: pageNumber = int(raw_input("Enter 4 or 5: "))

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this:-

`pageNumber = raw_input("Enter 4 or 5: ")` With `pageNumber = input("Enter 4 or 5: ")`

**Note :-** If you are using python 3 `input()` will work same as `raw_input()` in python2.7 so there you need to use it like `int(input("Enter 4 or 5: "))`. There is no `raw_input()` in python3.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the returned type of the `raw_input`. Right now, this is picking up a `str` which should be an `int`! Try changing your code to:

```
pageNumber = int(raw_input("Enter 4 or 5: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python2.* use `pageNumber = input("Enter 4 or 5: ")` or if you are using python3 you can use `pageNumber = int(input("Enter 4 or 5: "))`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason to operate on the number the user inputs i would update the if statement to be:

```
if pageNumber == "4":
```

this will compare them as strings. The elif statement also needs updating:

```
elif pageNumber == "5":
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is `raw_input()` will always treat whatever you are inputting as a string so when you are taking input, let's say `4`, it is treated as a string and then it is making a comparation with that string `4` to a int `4(`if pageNumber == 4:`) What you can do is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import webbrowser

print '\033[0;37;40m' + "Title: The interlinked bit (the index)"
print "Heading: Links!"
print "Paragraph Some Interesting stuff can be found here"
print "Paragraph: And some other bits are also available"
print "1: ./page4.html"
print "2: /page5.html"

pageNumber = raw_input("Enter 4 or 5: ")
if pageNumber == '4': #this
  print "A Page of stuff"; 
  print "Actually this is all rather dull, why don't you look here           instead, or alternatively    go back  to the index";
elif pageNumber == '5': #this
  print "Another page of stuff"
  print "Nothing very much here, you should probably try here instead, or       perhaps go back to the index"
```

Input:

```
4
```

Output:

```
Title: The interlinked bit (the index)
Heading: Links!
Paragraph Some Interesting stuff can be found here
Paragraph: And some other bits are also available
1: ./page4.html
2: /page5.html
Enter 4 or 5:  4
A Page of stuff
Actually this is all rather dull, why don't you look here           instead, or alternatively    go back  to the index
```